# custom R Markdown plot size within loop

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I'm creating strip plots within a R Markdown/knittr document.  I would the like vertical size of the plots to be proportional to the number of rows in the strip plot.

**EDIT:  The best solution would also allow interleaving of tables and plots.  See [Interleaving tables and plots in R Markdown, within loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792781/interleaving-tables-and-plots-in-r-markdown-within-loop)**

In this example, the plot for MPG for cars with "3 Carburetors" is the same height as the plot for cars with "2 Carburetors", even though there are three different gear configurations for 2-Carburetor cars and only one for 3-Carburetor cars.

[image]

[image]

````
```{r cars, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)

carb.possibilities <- sort(unique(as.character(mtcars$carb)))

filtereds <- lapply(carb.possibilities, function(carb.ct) {
  return(mtcars[ mtcars$carb == carb.ct , ])
})

carb.possibilities <- paste(carb.possibilities, ' Carburetors', sep = '')

names(filtereds) <- carb.possibilities

lapply(carb.possibilities, function(one.possibility) {

  current.possibility <- filtereds[[one.possibility]]

    ggplot(current.possibility, aes(factor(gear), mpg)) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    labs(x = "Gears", title = one.possibility) +
    geom_point(position=position_jitter( width = 0.1, height = 0.1) ) 
})
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using grid.arrange

````
```{r cars, echo=FALSE, fig.height=30}
library(ggplot2); library(gridExtra)

carb.possibilities <- sort(unique(as.character(mtcars$carb)))

filtereds <- lapply(carb.possibilities, function(carb.ct) {
  return(mtcars[ mtcars$carb == carb.ct , ])
})

carb.possibilities <- paste(carb.possibilities, ' Carburetors', sep = '')

names(filtereds) <- carb.possibilities
p <- list()
k <- 1
heights <- c()
for(one.possibility in carb.possibilities){
  current.possibility <- filtereds[[one.possibility]]
    heights[k] <- length(unique(current.possibility$gear))
    p[[k]] <- ggplot(current.possibility, aes(factor(gear), mpg)) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    labs(x = "Gears", title = one.possibility) +
    geom_point(position=position_jitter( width = 0.1, height = 0.1)) 
    k <- k + 1
}

do.call(grid.arrange, c(p, list(ncol = 1, heights= heights)))

```
````

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow.  Maybe I should have said that I was planning on  interleaving some text and tables between each plot.  Do you thunk that would be compatible with your solution?

Comment: Yes... just use grid.arrange with the height argument, e.g. grid.arrange(p[[1]], heights = height[1]). And you can do multiple plots like grid.arrange(p[1:2], heights = height[1:2]).

Comment: In terms of the proportional figure heights, this solution is perfect.  The number of plots won’t be constant from report to report, so I made the figure height proportional `(fig.height=length(unique(as.character(mtcars$carb))) * 2 )`.  I don't think I understand your response to my point about interleaving text...  if I add `print(one.possibility)` into the loop, all of the print statements get  bunched together at the top, but that also happens with my existing code.  I guess I need to post another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792781/interleaving-tables-and-plots-in-r-markdown-within-loop