# Interleaving tables and plots in R Markdown, within loop

Tags: r, loops, knitr, r-markdown

I have a R Markdown/knittr document that generates pairs of plots and tables.  The number of pairs is variable, so I create them inside of a loop.  **I would like the results to be interleaved in the output:  table 1, plot 1, table 2, plot 2...**

In the example below, all tables come first at the top of the document.  I have tried various permutations of

- pander or kable as my table function
- wrapping the table function in print or leaving it bare
- with or without *results='asis'*

***EDIT:  I found a solution and posted it below.  Now I'm looking for one that's compatible with the great variable-height advice I received in [custom R Markdown plot size within loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779573/custom-r-markdown-plot-size-within-loop) ?***

````
```{r cars, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)

carb.possibilities <- sort(unique(as.character(mtcars$carb)))

filtereds <- lapply(carb.possibilities, function(carb.ct) {
  return(mtcars[ mtcars$carb == carb.ct , ])
})

carb.possibilities <- paste(carb.possibilities, ' Carburetors', sep = '')

names(filtereds) <- carb.possibilities

lapply(carb.possibilities, function(one.possibility) {

  current.possibility <- filtereds[[one.possibility]]

  print(kable(current.possibility))

  ggplot(current.possibility, aes(factor(gear), mpg)) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    labs(x = "Gears", title = one.possibility) +
    geom_point(position=position_jitter( width = 0.1, height = 0.1) ) 
})
```
````

Comment: i would use `for(one.possibility in carb.possibilities){`, instead of lapply, and the n`print(ggplot(...))`

Comment: Great, that definitely interleaves the tables and plots, as long as the table is wrapped in print.  Unfortunately, that means that the tables lose their nice kable formatting.  PS, why do you prefer a for loop instead of lappy?

Comment: Also, I don’t see how I could use this along with the outside-of-loop `do.call(grid.arrange...)` in the answer I linked.

Comment: I would prefer a loop as you are just printing rather than returning a value. Plus using lapply with print seems to return the ggplot object.

Comment: i dont see how you could interleave tables while joining plots together with grid.arrange.

Comment: So by combining your two questions, really what you want is that tables and plots are interleaved but that each plot height is determined by the number of levels in the plot?

Comment: Right.  AND the table should be pretty-formatted, not just fixed-width ASCII  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using asis, wrapping both the table and plot in print() and cat'ing a linefeed solve the interleaving problem.  I haven’t figured how to combine this with the variable height plots from [custom R Markdown plot size within loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779573/custom-r-markdown-plot-size-within-loop)

See https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/886

````
```{r cars, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)

carb.possibilities <- sort(unique(as.character(mtcars$carb)))

filtereds <- lapply(carb.possibilities, function(carb.ct) {
  return(mtcars[ mtcars$carb == carb.ct , ])
})

carb.possibilities <- paste(carb.possibilities, ' Carburetors', sep = '')

names(filtereds) <- carb.possibilities

for(one.possibility in carb.possibilities){

  current.possibility <- filtereds[[one.possibility]]

  my.ggplot <- ggplot(current.possibility, aes(factor(gear), mpg)) +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(x = "Gears", title = one.possibility) +
    geom_point(position=position_jitter( width = 0.1, height = 0.1) )

  print(kable(current.possibility))

  cat('\n')

  print(my.ggplot)

}
```
````

Comment: one way to change the heights is to have an earlier chunk with the heights defined (ie `heights <- aggregate(gear ~ carb, mtcars, function(x) length(unique(x)))$gear ; heights <- paste0(2*heights, 'in')`), and then pass this to the `out.height` argument in the next chunk with the plots (ie. `out.height=heights`). However, I don't know how to get consistent plot widths. (although if width was constant then the plots would look stretched)